# Magento 2.3 add custom block under each product in category page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category-products, custom-block, list.phtml

I need to overwrite the product listing (category) page, a custom form needs to show after that product information.

So I have found that already an extension is overwriting that page as below

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_ModuleName::list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

How to add that custom form after the each products from my custom module?
[image]
Please advise.

Comment: What is purpose of this block class.You have to call your block at Custom_ModuleName::list.phtml inside for each loop

Comment: Hi Amit, the purpose is I have to show grid-based form to fill quantity. How to call by block in third party extension? please share some code if possible

Comment: Please check my last update also.

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thank you. Let me try and update you. Can I able to call a phtml file in that method? As I have to show a form to add to cart.

Comment: Yes. You can do anything in this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create **di.xml** file at `/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` :

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="block-product-list" type="Vender\Module\Plugin\ProductList"/>
</type>
```

Create **Plugin** file **ProductList.php** at `/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin` :

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Plugin;

class ProductList
{   
    protected $layout;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
    ) {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        return $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Moduele\Block\YourBlock')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::yourPhtml.phtml')->toHtml();
    }               
}
```

**UPDATE :**

For display in catalog search also you need to create

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="block-product-list" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ProductList" />
</virtualType>
```

Clean cache and refresh page.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the text under each product, but can you share how to call a phtml file to show a form (for add to cart)

Comment: Please check my updated code and let me know if still not working.

Comment: @Antony It's working now?

Comment: checking will update you. thanks again.

Comment: sorry receiving error as `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function vendor\Blkord\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct::__construct(), 0 passed in ` Interceptor.php 

, In my block constructor 
```public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }```

Comment: Did you remove generated and clean cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96086/discussion-between-antony-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Rohan, in that phtml file how to get the product object. as mentioned that i have to done the add to cart functionality here. please advise.

Comment: Using $product you can get current product object.

Comment: In that phtml I have tried $product->getId(); but it is throughing error as $product

Comment: Let me check that..

Comment: Hi, any solution?

Comment: using this I can able to get $block->getProduct()->getId();

Comment: Very helpful code please keep commenting this type of code @RohanHapani